# Can I store the value of a C# property with a single class member?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class with the two following members:

```
private _something;
public something
{
    get
    {
        return _something;
    }

    set
    {
        // ... Manipulate value ...
        _something = value;
    }
}
```

I'd like to use `get { }` and `set { }` without referring to the separate member, but keep this same functionality. Is there a mechanism to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?  Why don't you want to store the value in the variable?

Comment: you need to add a bit more detail since it's not clear what you want to do. you don't need to refer to the separate member - you can for example do get { return true; } or perform some other evaluation.

Comment: how would you manipulate the value if it wasn't stored some where else? even when you declare

    public something { get;set;} 

the compiler creates a variable to store the value in.

Comment: After some thought: I'd like to treat the property `something` as an object I can assign a value to. With this code, I'd like to change the accessor to `get { return this.something; }`. I don't want to separate this property as another variable, with a slightly different name. Just looking to see if C# had a solution for this!

Comment: @Airzooka: Well, you can return whatever you like from a `get`.  It just needs to be the correct return type.

Comment: @David: But of course. I'm looking for a mechanism, if any exists, to treat `something` as an assignable member -- while keeping the getter and setter.

Comment: @Airzooka: You can also do whatever you like in a `set`.  Can you show something you've tried and explain how it isn't working?  Because there's nothing stopping you from creating a property that does whatever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are asking whether you can use an auto-implemented property while you have a some logic in your setter method.The answer is **no**, you can't. You have to provide a backing field explicitly.

An auto-implemented property is also using a backing field created by the compiler.So there has to be something to store the value because a property is just a syntactic sugar for `get` and `set` methods.